# SQL query to exclude sessions under 2 minutes

Tags: mysql, datetime

Im am trying to write a code that will remove any entires that are within 2 mins of each other on the same day for each user_id.

for example here is the table:

| user_id | day | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 00:55:54 |
| x | 1 | 00:55:55 |
| x | 1 | 00:56:01 |
| x | 2 | 16:11:43 |
| x | 2 | 16:12:01 |
| x | 2 | 16:15:02 |
| x | 2 | 16:30:07 |
| x | 2 | 16:31:08 |
| x | 2 | 16:40:09 |
| x | 2 | 16:41:02 |

So if within the same day there was some times that didn't last more than 2 mins i would like to exclude does 2 entires.

Comment: so in your set are you only expecting `16:15:02` to be the only row left?

Comment: Your request should include the expected result. Please edit it and add that result table. From your explanation I, too, suppose you only want to select the 16:15:02 row, because it is the only row that has neither a preceding row nor a following row within two minutes.

Comment: theoretically: if a user on day X starts sessions within 120secs from one another for an hour, do you still want to count it as one session? In other words: are you looking for consecutive sessions 2min apart or the gaps of > 2mins?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to compose time frames and then filter only those frames that are shorter than 120 seconds:

```sql
WITH frames AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, day, time AS start, 
    COALESCE(
      LEAD(time) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, day), 
      '23:59:59'
    ) AS final
  FROM sessions
)
SELECT 
  user_id, day, start, final, TIMEDIFF(final, start) AS duration 
FROM frames
WHERE TIMEDIFF(final, start) < 120
```

Comment: when i run this i get this error "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'starttime' in 'field list'"

Comment: No column in the above query is named `starttime`.

Comment: my bad i get an error saying: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'start' in 'field list'"

Comment: is frame referring to the time column when you say: "WITH frames as" on the first line

Comment: The query was tested on DBfiddle and is working. Is your MySQL an older version?

Comment: yes i have an old version of sql this is the code I'm running:

Comment: `WITH frames AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, day(timestamp), time(timestamp) AS starttime, COALESCE(
  LEAD(time(timestamp)) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, day(timestamp)), 
  '23:59:59'
  ) AS final
  FROM events
)
SELECT user_id, day(timestamp), starttime, final, TIMEDIFF(final, starttime) AS duration 
FROM frames
WHERE TIMEDIFF(final, starttime) < 120;`

Comment: but now im getting `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'field list'`